# Common holomorphic forms for two distinct complex structures

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a closed real surface having two complex structures $c_1$ and $c_2$ which are not biholomorphic (so $S$ is a Riemann surface with genus at least 1). Consider $\omega$ a 1-form on $S$ which is holomorphic for both $c_1$ and $c_2$. Can we conclude that $\omega=0$ ?

Intuitively I would proceed as follows. Since $\omega$ is holomorphic for $c_1$, I would write $\omega= f(z) dz$ in conformal coordinates around a given point in $S$. Then, I would compare the Cauchy–Riemann equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$ : since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not biholomorphic, the Cauchy–Riemann equations should take the form $\partial_{\bar{z}} f = 0$ for $c_1$ and some linear combination $\alpha \partial_x f + \beta \partial_y f=0$, with $\beta/\alpha \neq -i$ for $c_2$. So the derivatives of $f$ vanish.
So $\omega$ should be proportional to $dz$, in every choice of conformal coordinates for $c_1$. But the same also holds for $c_2$. So the only possibility should be $\omega=0$.

Comment: A function $g$ is holomorphic if and only if $dg\wedge \omega=0$, for $\omega\ne 0$ holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $C^1$ function $g$ on a connected Riemann surface is holomorphic if and only if $dg\wedge \omega=0$, for $\omega$ holomorphic and not the zero form. Where $\omega\ne 0$ this is clear, expanding out in a holomorphic coordinate, say $\omega=f(z)\,dz$, and then integrating along curves to construct a local holomorphic coordinate $Z=\int f(z)\,dz$ so that $\omega=dZ$. Expand out to find that if $g=u+iv$ and $Z=x+iy$ then
$$dg\wedge\omega=du\wedge dx-dv\wedge dy+i(du\wedge dy+dv\wedge dx),\\=((-u_y-v_x)+i(u_x-v_y))dx\wedge dy,$$
vanishing just when the Cauchy--Riemann equations are satisfied.  Elsewhere it follows by continuity. Hence the complex structures are identical.

Comment: Are you sure about this condition $dg\wedge \omega$ ? Because on the torus for instance, there exists complex structures which are not identical...

Comment: On the torus, there are many complex structures, each of which admits a global complex linear nowhere vanishing holomorphic $1$-form, but these are not complex linear multiples of one another, if the complex structures are different, so each has conjugate linear parts with respect to the other, and their wedge product is not zero. One might be, in some linear coordinates, $\xi=dx+i\,dy$, while another is $\eta=dx+2i\,dy$. It is easy linear algebra to compute out that $\xi\wedge\eta\ne 0$, so the condition $dg\wedge\xi=0$ is linearly independent of $dg\wedge\eta=0$.